# Can we add border around the chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, border, lightningchart

Using LightningchartJS, I want to add border around the chart.Is there any API available to achieve this?
I did tried a lot of existing API's though.

Comment: Can you please be more specific, do you mean border around the whole chart, or just the graph area?

Comment: Yup, i wanted to say, around graph area.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the graph area border with [Chart.setChartBackgroundStroke](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.2/classes/chartxy.html#setchartbackgroundstroke)

```js
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()

chart.setChartBackgroundStroke( new SolidLine( { 
    fillStyle: new SolidFill( { color: ColorRGBA( 200,0,0 ) } ), 
    thickness: 2 
} ) )
```